# May one install a web cam to check in on an elderly parent?

Tags: technology, tznius-modesty, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

With a friend, I discussed the idea of installing a web cam to check in on an elderly parent who lives in her apartment alone and is serviced by a Gentile aid. The children are concerned that the aid may be neglecting or abusing the parent, and they want to install a hidden web cam in the bedroom, dining room and kitchen to assure themselves that their parent is safe and being treated properly.

My friend said that he thought that one should not install a web cam, because one might accidentally view the cam while their parent is undressed and see their parent's nakedness (problem of *tzni'ut*, possibly.)

Would this or any other similar concern alone cause a prohibition against installing a web cam, or would one's general concern for the parent's safety and security override this concern?

Comment: As for accidently seeing your parent's nakedness, what about instances in which people are attendants for their own parents or elderly rabbis? They have to see the nakedness at some point, but they make extra effort to not look and shame them. I think your concern would override any concerns with seeing a parent undressed. Besides, if this does happen, quickly deactivate the camera to avoid seeing them anymore. Just do not make an effort to see them undressed with the camera.

Comment: @Ezra sounds like a good point. Can you form an answer?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with parents, but just general security for the incapacitated. You tagged this [tag:kibbud-av-vaem-honoring] for no reason that I can see.

Comment: @DanF - As of now I need more sources to make my claim based in fact and able to be relied on.

Comment: Is this assumed to be with the parent's knowledge and consent?  Or is the parent not cogent enough to understand?

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand that we have a stronger obligation to parents than to others, so it's possible that the general answer would be no while the answer in the case of a parent would be yes.  Or the other way around, depending on which of safety/*kibbud* takes priority.  If the answer is the same for all situations, an answer could address that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The parent has dementia, Altzheimer's or is otherwise not mentally capable to decide or be aware of what is happening.